# Converter PDF para DOC

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi

É possível converter um PDF para um documento word mantendo no documento convertido todas as formatações, alinhamentos, fontes e tabelas, utilizando apache-poi ou alguma outra api?

Answer (score 2):

Que formato Doc é que pretendes? (.doc ou .docx)?

Uma das maneiras de converteres vários formatos de texto (open office e microsoft office) é instalares o Libre office no teu pc. Depois sacas o JODConverter e é só fazeres isto:

```
File inputFile = new File("document.doc");
File outputFile = new File("document.pdf");

// connect to an OpenOffice.org instance running on port 8100
OpenOfficeConnection connection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
connection.connect();

// convert
DocumentConverter converter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(connection);
converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);

// close the connection
connection.disconnect();
```

Nota: Cuidado com a instância do Libre office

Apache POI é capaz de fazer isso (Apache TIKA é mais completo, mas também mais "pesado"). O Itext também quase de certeza faz isso.

Basicamente está tudo aqui:

http://www.javadomain.in/convert-pdf-to-word-in-java-example/